# How to double fork from a Python web server without leaving a zombie process?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Python 3.6

I have a simple Python web server that, when it receives a POST request, spawns a netcat process to listen on a port.

Seems to work OK except that a zombie is left following the spawn.

(Server code below)

I send a POST request to the server like so:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "example data"  localhost:8000
```

After that I do a ps ax to see the processes running and the netcat process is there, the web server is there, AND a zombie is there.

```
6873 pts/0    S+     0:00 python3 nc_server.py
6876 ?        Zs     0:00 [python3] <defunct>
6877 ?        S      0:00 nc -l 54927
```

Why?  How can I avoid the zombie?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socket
import os
import io

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8000

def find_free_port():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(('', 0))
        return s.getsockname()[1]

def spawn_netcat(port):
    command = "/bin/nc"
    params = f"nc -l {port}"
    spawnDaemon(command, params.split())

def spawnDaemon(path_to_executable, params):

    # Do first fork
    pid = os.fork()
    if (pid != 0):
        return

    # Decouple from parent environment
    os.chdir("/opt")
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)

    # Do second fork
    pid = os.fork()
    if (pid != 0):
        os._exit(0)

    # exec this process into netcat.....
    os.execv(path_to_executable, params)

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        netcat_listen_port = find_free_port()
        spawn_netcat(netcat_listen_port)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
        self.end_headers()
        response = io.BytesIO()
        response.write(str(netcat_listen_port).encode())
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    httpd = HTTPServer((host, port), Server)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Why are you testing `os.getpid() == web_server_pid`?

Comment: It's not really needed but I wanted to ensure I was not killing the web server process.  The code above is actually culled down to a minimal example of the problem from a larger code base, so that test is unnecessary, I should have removed it for this example. The return statement is needed of course, just not its enclosing if statement. OK I have removed it now from the code for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @user2357112, Any particular reason you rolled back my edit?

Comment: @merlin2011 the edit removed the f prefix on the string which indicates string interpolation.

Comment: Because a parent process is meant at some point to wait on the sub process PID to get back the status. Until that happens it will be listed as a zombie. It will not consume resources except a slot in the process table where status is kept.

Comment: @merlin2011: It looks like you may be unaware of [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). A leading `f` on a string is not an automatic syntax error; it indicates that f-string interpolation should be performed.

Comment: @user2357112, Thanks for the clarification! Indeed, I was not aware of them.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton would you mind suggesting what I can change in my code to prevent the zombie being created? thanks!

Comment: When you kill your web server, does your "nc" command gets killed as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process terminates, it expects its return code to be collected by its parent. Until this takes place, it sits there undead (zombie), it no longer runs, but it cannot be cleared from process table in peace. If the parent is no longer around, a process would get re-parented to init (or dedicated reaper process on at least some systemd enabled systems IIRC). In your process list, you are seeing child of the first fork, which has its parent around, but not collecting the return status.

Long story short, past the first `fork()`, you can insert this just before `return` in the parent process:

```
os.waitid(os.P_PID, pid, os.WEXITED)
```

I.e.:

```
# Do first fork
pid = os.fork()
if (pid != 0):
    os.waitid(os.P_PID, pid, os.WEXITED)
    return
```

This child only is short lived and exits. This waits for it to do so before returning out of the function. It should be fine in this case. Otherwise in general if your process spawns children that may exit at any later point, you'd register a `SIGCHLD` handler to take care of this. Even though except for double fork to daemonize, you would normally use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and interface with your process using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).